# Rails 3 : How to merge/pass param from text_field to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textfield

How can I merge my TextField param to my current params (and thus stay on the same page , ideally without page refresh)

I managed to pass static params like

```
params.merge(:myParam => "ok")
```

But in that case , the Text_Field will be modified (using JQuery) by the user and stored into an (hidden) Text_Field. Then I want to get that value and pass it to my controller :

```
<%= text_field_tag(:myTextField) %>
<%= link_to 'Convert and Retrieve' , params.merge(:run => params[:myTextField]) %>
```

I'm happy to detail it a bit more if that doesn't make sense, Thank you